# Getting model significance and adj R for function in R

Tags: r, quantreg

Sample Data:

```
  ##Data preperation 
  set.seed(5) 
  d <- data.frame(x=seq(-5, 5, len=51)) 
  d$y <- 50 - 0.3*d$x^2 + rnorm(nrow(d))
```

Function:

```
     Qr=function(x,y,taus) {
     QUA5<-quantreg::rq(y ~ 1 + x + I(x^2)+I(x^3)+I(x^4)+I(x^5), tau=0.5, data=d)
     return(summary(QUA5,se="boot"))
}
```

I want not only the parameter sign but also the model sign and the R^2 or adj R^2 if possible!

Comment: Use the output from `summary` and `sapply` or use pipes to get the R.squared?

Comment: @NelsonGon sapply function is not working!, and what is pipes!

Comment: Could you add some data with which to test your function and any library calls? Also add what you have tried already so that it is not repeated.

Comment: @NelsonGon                                                                                                    ##Data preperation
set.seed(5)
data <- data.frame(x=seq(-5, 5, len=51))
data$y <- 50 - 0.3*d$x^2 + rnorm(nrow(d))                                                                          I want to get the model sign for these data based on the model in the main question

Comment: You will have to do so manually. See: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129200/r-squared-in-quantile-regression